# Check if an element is within a sequence

Tags: f#

how to check if an element is contained within a sequence? I expected some Seq.contains, but i could not find it. Thanks

**EDIT**:
Or, for an easier task, how to make the diff between two sequences? Like, getting all the elements within a list that doesn not belong to another (or that do)?

Comment: For your second question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158114/f-seq-diff

Answer (score 38):

Little bit simpler:

```
let contains x = Seq.exists ((=) x)
```

Comment: What is that `(=)` syntax called please?

Comment: It's just an operator, but wrapped in a brackets behaves like a normal function. Operators consist of special characters (like '=') that are not recognized as function name.
For example:

`let z = x + y  // is the same like
let z = (+) x y`

Answer (score 6):

Seq.exists

```
let testseq = seq [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
let equalsTwo n = (n = 2)
let containsTwo = Seq.exists equalsTwo testseq
```

Answer (score 5):

`Set` is your friend here:

```
let a = set [0;1;2;3]
let b = set [2;3;4;5]
let c = a - b
let d = b - a
let e = Set.intersect a b
let f = a + b
> 
val c : Set<int> = seq [0; 1]
val d : Set<int> = seq [4; 5]
val e : Set<int> = seq [2; 3]
val f : Set<int> = seq [0; 1; 2; 3; ...]
```

Danny

Answer (score 2):

Seq.exists again, but with slightly different syntax -

```
let testseq = seq [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
let testn = 2
testseq |> Seq.exists (fun x -> x = testn)
```

See MSDN F#: Seq.exists function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353562.aspx

Lots of other good ones there too!

Answer (score 0):

(Another question, another answer.)

This works, but I don't think that it's the most idomatic way to do it - (you'll need to wait until the US wakes up to find out):

```
let s1 = seq [ 1; 2; 3; 4 ]
let s2 = seq [ 3; 4; 5; 6 ]

seq {
    for a in s1 do
        if not (Seq.exists (fun n -> n = a) s2) then
            yield a
        }
```

Comment: What you have is an O(nm) algorithm, where n is the length of the first list and m is the length of the second. When n and m are approximately equal to one another, you might as well consider this an O(n^2) algorithm. I think there are much more efficient ways to compute the intersection of a set than this.