# F# Seq diff

Tags: f#

given two sequences, how to get all the elements belonging to both the sequences or all the elements unique to one of them?

Example:

```
let a = [1..10]
let b = [3; 5; 7]
```

How do I compute 3 5 and 7 (all the elements *common* to both the list) and 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10 (all the elements *not in common*)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want to do is no more than the simple set operations of [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) and [difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement) (or relative complement).

F# has the `Set` module to help us out here. This should do the job:

```
let a = [1 .. 10]
let b = [3; 5; 7]

let intersection = Set.intersect (Set.ofList a) (Set.ofList b)
let difference = (Set.ofList a) - (Set.ofList b)
```

You can then of course convert back the results into lists using `Set.toList`, if you wish.

As Mehrdad points out, this can be done alternatively using LINQ (or even the `HashSet` class in the BCL), but the approach here would seem to be most in the spirit of the F# language (certainly the nicest syntactically, and probably the most efficient too).

Comment: Something to think about is that by converting a list to a set, only the distinct values are preserved (definition of a set). The answer given by Mehrdad (using Linq-Enumerable methods) will keep all the values, even distinct ones. Sometimes this is not a problem but I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: (Set.of_list a) - (Set.of_list b) is not commutative

Answer (score 9):

Slightly more compact:

```
let a = set [0;1;2;3]
let b = set [2;3;4;5]
let c = a - b
let d = b - a
let e = Set.intersect a b
let f = a + b
> 
val c : Set<int> = seq [0; 1]
val d : Set<int> = seq [4; 5]
val e : Set<int> = seq [2; 3]
val f : Set<int> = seq [0; 1; 2; 3; ...]
```

Danny

Answer (score 5):

Not very F#-y way I know of. You can always resort to .NET libraries. `seq<T>` is just `IEnumerable<T>`, nothing special:

```
let diff = System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(seq1, seq2); // seq1 - seq2
let intersect = System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect(seq1, seq2);
let symdiff = System.Linq.Enumerable.Union(System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(seq1, seq2), System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(seq2, seq1));
```

Comment: They work, but I think it is strange for a language that works so heavily with sequences not having its own methods (or aliases) for such a common task ...

Comment: Agreed. There might be a more F#y way. Just mentioned the possibility. Waiting for a better answer.