# f# Finding the difference between 2 obj[]lists

Tags: arrays, list, f#

I have 2 obj[]lists list1 and list2. List1 has a length of 8 and list2 has a length of 10. There are arrays in list1 that only exist in list1. That also goes the same for list2. But there are array that exist in both. I'm wondering how to get the arrays that exist in list1. At the moment when I run my code I get a list of the arrays that exist in both lists, but it's missing the data unique to list1. I'm wondering how to get that unique list1 data. Any suggestions?

```
let getProdOnly (index:int)(list1:obj[]list)(list2:obj[]list) =
    let mutable list3 = list.Empty
    for i = 0 to list1.Length-1 do
        for j = 0 to list2.Length-1 do
            if list1.Item(i).GetValue(index).Equals(list2.Item(j).GetValue(index)) then
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exists in List 1 and 2")
            else
                list3 <- list1.Item(i)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Seq diff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158114/f-seq-diff)

Comment: Indexing into an F# List! Augh, my eyes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let ar1 = [|1;2;3|]
let ar2 = [|2;3;4|]
let s1 = ar1 |> Set.ofArray
let s2 = ar2 |> Set.ofArray
Set.difference s1 s2
//val it : Set<int> = set [1]
```

There are also a bunch of `Array` related functions, like compareWith, distinct, exists if you want to work with Arrays directly.

But as was pointed out in previous answers, this type of imperative code is not very idiomatic. Try to avoid mutable variables, try to avoid loops. It could probably rewritten with `Array.map` for example.

Comment: This assumes no duplicate values. If duplicate values are to be preserved then power sets or somthing, are the answer. But then there are no native lib for that in F3 to my knowledge.

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm I agree. This all depends on the data and the intent. One can certainly just check each input array and accumulate the results.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the elements unique to one list, this is the easiest way to do it in F# 4.0:

```
list1
|> List.except list2
```

which will remove all the elements of list2 from list1. Note that `except` also calls a distinct, so you might need to watch out for that.

Answer (score 2):

First I took your code with minor changes and added some printf debuging to see what is does.

```
let getProdOnly2 (index:int)(list1:obj[] list)(list2:obj[] list) =
    let mutable list3 : obj[] list= list.Empty
    for i = 0 to list1.Length-1 do
        for j = 0 to list2.Length-1 do
            if list1.[i].[index] = list2.[j].[index] then
                printfn "equal"
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exists in List 1 and 2")
                list3
            else
                printfn "add %A %A"  (list1.Item(i)) (list2.Item(j)) 
                list3 <- list1.Item(i) :: list3
                list3
    list3
```

And it does adding an element each time it finds an element not equal the current element. 
So my attempt is to take the list1 and just ceep or better filter the elements that are not part of list2.

```
let getProdOnly3 (index:int)(list1:obj[] list)(list2:obj[] list) =
    list1
    |> List.filter (fun el1 ->
        list2
        |> List.fold (fun acc el2 -> acc && (el2<>el1))  true )
```

I tested the code with the following lists

```
let list1 = [   [| 1;2;3;4|]
                [| 1;2;3;4|] 
                [| 2;3;4|]
                [| 3;4;5|] ] |> List.map (fun a -> a |> Array.map (fun e -> box e))

let list2 = [   [| 2;3;4|]
                [| 3;4;5|] ] |> List.map (fun a -> a |> Array.map (fun e -> box e))
```

In difference to s952163 my result will have double entries if list1 has double entries, do not know if that is wanted or unwanted beahyuvier.